# I am not able to add module in VScode to create multi module spring boot maven project

Tags: spring-boot, maven, multi-module

I am learning spring-boot and I am doing well with single projects. I am using VSCode. I am stuck with creation of multi module maven project. I know that it is easy to add modules in intellij but I want to continue using VScode which I like very much. I spent days browsing on this but I couldn't find anything that is helpful. Can some help in how I can create multi module spring boot project in VSCode?